# How to use the latest value of the state inside a useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

My component renders an image every 4 seconds. When I click on the image I want to stop rendering new images. For that I've used a useEffect hook. When I click to the image, the state `hasToRefresh` changes it's values, but inside useEffect it doesn't change. This is my code:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const VariableImage = () => {
  const imageUrl = "https://picsum.photos/200";
  const imageRefresh = "?forcerefresh=";

  const [image, setImage] = useState(imageUrl);
  const [hasToRefresh, setHasToRefresh] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasToRefresh) {
      setInterval(() => {
        setImage(imageUrl + imageRefresh + Math.random());
      }, 4000);
    }
  }, [imageUrl, imageRefresh, hasToRefresh]);

  return (
    <>
      <img
        src={image}
        onClick={() => setHasToRefresh(!hasToRefresh)}
        alt="scenery"
        height="200"
        width="200"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default VariableImage;
```

Also in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/variable-image-zxhejs

How can I do for when I click the image to not render more images?
If anyone could help me I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I have checked sandbox and when you click multiple times system create multiple setInterval you need to move those out into empty useEffect and when click need to clear interval change image and start interval that will fix your issue.

Comment: The issue is not with the value of ```hasToRefresh```. It seems you are not cancelling the subscription/ interval when your hasToRefresh value changes. You could do that by adding a else block

Comment: I have fixed this code you can verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Roy Schut mentioned, you never stop your timer. But the best option would be here to stop the timer when the image shouldn't be refreshed. Here's the code I would prefer.

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const VariableImage = () => {
  const imageUrl = "https://picsum.photos/200";
  const imageRefresh = "?forcerefresh=";

  const [image, setImage] = useState(imageUrl);
  const [hasToRefresh, setHasToRefresh] = useState(true);
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    startTimer();

    return () => stopTimer();
  }, []);

  const startTimer = () => {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setImage(imageUrl + imageRefresh + Math.random());
    }, 4000);
  };

  const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  };

  const toggleRefresh = () => {
    if (hasToRefresh) {
      stopTimer();
    } else {
      startTimer();
    }
    setHasToRefresh(state => !state);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <img
        src={image}
        onClick={() => toggleRefresh()}
        alt="scenery"
        height="200"
        width="200"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default VariableImage;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're never stopping your interval. And to only trigger the `useEffect()` for `hasToRefresh`, I would move the creation of image string outside of it.

```
 const VariableImage = () => {
  const imageUrl = "https://picsum.photos/200";
  const imageRefresh = "?forcerefresh=";
  const [imageNumber, setImageNumber] = useState(Math.random());
  const image = imageUrl + imageRefresh + imageNumber;
  const [hasToRefresh, setHasToRefresh] = useState(true);

  const intervalRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasToRefresh) {
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setImageNumber(Math.random());
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => {
      intervalRef.current && clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
      intervalRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [hasToRefresh]);

  return (
    <>
      <img
        src={image}
        onClick={() => setHasToRefresh(!hasToRefresh)}
        alt="scenery"
        height="200"
        width="200"
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Here's the updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/variable-image-forked-oxfgc9?file=/src/VariableImage/VariableImage.js:54-896

Comment: Thanks for your answer Roy. With that the image is rendered but never change.

Comment: You're right. For that I would actually take out the creation of the image url, so you don't need all the dependencies in the useEffect. I checked your sandbox and updated my code above.